# Counting characters inside words using .map

Tags: javascript, node.js, arrays, split, array.prototype.map

I'm having trouble with getting to the right answer, I'm currently in a course and I'm trying to make a sentance string that I input at the end (at console.log) count the characters for every word that I have, which means, if the sentence is " hey I'm mikey" then it will show [3, 2, 5]
this is my code:

```js
const IsstringArray = (StringsArray) => {
  return StringsArray.map(stringarraysplit => {
    stringarraysplit2 = stringarraysplit.split(" ")
    return stringarraysplit2.length
  })
}
console.log(IsstringArray(["hey my name is miki hey"]))
```

it shows the number of words, but I need the number of characters in those words.

Comment: Your first `map` does not iterate the words as you might think, but the whole sentence

Answer (score 1):

You can combine [Array#map()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map), [String#trim()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim) and [String#split()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Split)

Code:

```js
const caractersByArray = a =>
  a.map(s =>
    s
      .trim()
      .split(' ')
      .map(s => s.length)
  )

const result = caractersByArray([
  "hey my name is miki hey", 
  " hey I'm mikey"
])

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Notice that `" hey I'm mikey"` --> `[3, 3, 5]` because `'` also counts

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
const IsstringArray = (StringsArray) => {
    const stringarraysplit = StringsArray.split(" ")
    return stringarraysplit.map(stringarraysplit => { 
        return stringarraysplit.length;})
}  

console.log(IsstringArray("hey my name is miki hey"))
```